# Tkinter PIL image not displaying inside of a function

Tags: python, function, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am using Tkinter to display images in a Toplevel() but when I put it inside of a function it doesn't work(This is very beginner I know)

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
from tkMessageBox import *
import Image, ImageTk
import PIL.Image, PIL.ImageTk
import os
import subprocess


root = Tk()
root.title("Test")
quin=Toplevel()    
C = Tkinter.Canvas(quin, bg="white", height = 350, width = 350)   
directory=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
filename=os.path.join(directory, 'un.png')
img=PIL.Image.open(filename)
tkimg=PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
image = C.create_image(175,175,image=tkimg)
C.grid(row=5,column=5)
def Head():
     h1 = Label(root, text = "How to Secure a Computer", fg ="white", bg = "#00b8ff", width = 6,bd=2, height =2, font = "Arial", relief = RAISED)
     h1.grid(row= 0, column = 0, ipadx=122, pady=3, padx=5,columnspan=3)
def Mainmenu():
    menubar = Menu(root)
    filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.destroy)
    menubar.add_cascade(label="Options", menu=filemenu)
    helpmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    helpmenu.add_radiobutton(label="Help")
    helpmenu.add_radiobutton(label="User Manual Security Configuration Guide")
    menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpmenu)
    root.config(menu=menubar)

def Mainbuttons():
    B1=Button(root,text="Services",height=2, width=6,bd=2, font = "Arial", fg = "#FFFFFF", bg = "#156cff",command=Services)
    B2=Button(root,text="Account Policies",height=2, width=6,bd=2, font = "Arial", fg = "#FFFFFF", bg = "#156cff")
    B3=Button(root,text="Firewall Config",height=2, width=6,bd=2, font = "Arial", fg = "#FFFFFF", bg = "#156cff")
    B4=Button(root,text="User Logon Time",height=2, width=6,bd=2, font = "Arial", fg = "#FFFFFF", bg = "#156cff")
    B5=Button(root,text="Security Policies",height=2, width=6,bd=2, font = "Arial", fg = "#FFFFFF", bg = "#156cff")
    B1.grid(row = 1, column = 0, ipadx=120,pady=2,padx=5)
    B2.grid(row = 1, column = 1, ipadx=120,pady=2,padx=5)
    B3.grid(row = 2, column = 1, ipadx=120,pady=2,padx=5)
    B4.grid(row = 2, column = 0, ipadx=120,pady=2,padx=5)
    B5.grid(row = 3, column = 0, ipadx=120,pady=2,padx=5)

def Services():
    serv=Toplevel()
    servcanv=Canvas(serv,height=250, width=250)
    servtext=Text(serv,width=26)
    servtext.insert(INSERT, "To start go to your start menu, in the search bar\ntype services.msc")
    servtext.grid(row=0, column=0)
    servcanv.grid(row=0, column=1)
    s = Tkinter.Canvas(serv, bg="white", height = 350, width = 350)   
    directory=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    filename=os.path.join(directory, 'un.png')
    img=PIL.Image.open(filename)
    tkimg=PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    image=s.create_image(175,175,image=tkimg)
    s.grid(row=5,column=5)





Mainmenu()
Mainbuttons()   
Head()
root.mainloop()
```

As you can see the code used to display the image is used twice, once inside a function and once outside. When outside it works perfectly, but when inside it doesn't work, it says the variable image is assigned but never used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does not work inside function, since `tkimg` is garbage collected after function finishes. You need to bind your images into variables that wont be garbage collected. For example to global variables, or instance variables in a class, rather than local variables.

To make `tkimg` be able to write to the global `tkimg` use `global tkimg` in the function.

Comment: It's supposed to be a local version, though, that only appears in the new `Toplevel` window.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 So it wont work. `tkimg` is still being garbage collected when `Services` function finish. Need to make other global variable to hold the reference to the image you want to use.

Comment: It works as you said, I made the `tkimg` a global and it worled.