# Python Tkinter Image issue in definition

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
def displayimage():
   Initimage=Tk()
   Initimage.title('Initializing')
   photo1=PhotoImage(file='AMAS.gif')
    Label(Initimage,image=photo1,bg='black').grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=E)
    Initimage.resizable(0,0)
    Initimage.mainloop()

displayimage()
```

This is the code

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\vinayak\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 1705, in **call**
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Users\vinayak\Documents\Programs 12th\Project.py", line 292, in submitact
logintodb(user, passw)
File "C:\Users\vinayak\Documents\Programs 12th\Project.py", line 319, in logintodb
displayimage()
File "C:\Users\vinayak\Documents\Programs 12th\Project.py", line 260, in displayimage
Label(Initimage,image=photo1,bg='black').grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=E)
File "C:\Users\vinayak\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 2766, in **init**
Widget.**init**(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
File "C:\Users\vinayak\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 2299, in **init**
(widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist

Comment: can you show us exactly how where you trying to implement it? the error you showed there doesnt correspond with the code you posted

Comment: Please post the code that is causing the error. You are letting us guess...

Comment: I've Updated the post

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter PIL image not displaying inside of a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29401873/tkinter-pil-image-not-displaying-inside-of-a-function)

Comment: @jasonharper that didn't work either can you please help

Comment: I think you have another instance of `Tk()` elsewhere in your code.  Try adding `master=Initimage` to `photo1=PhotoImage(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

Function implementation sample,Added mainloop() to display continuously

```
from tkinter import *
def displayimage():
    Initimage=Tk()
    Initimage.title('Initializing')
    photo1=PhotoImage(file='AMAS.gif')
    Label(Initimage,image=photo1,bg='black').grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=E)
    Initimage.resizable(0,0)
    Initimage.mainloop()

displayimage()
```