# Moviepy: Displaying Final file of clip in tkinter window error

Tags: python, tkinter, moviepy

I am trying to build a small video editor using a Tkinter GUI and Moviepy.

The start/end times of the desired subclip are entered by the user. The error occurs when the user does not specify the end time (the program uses the duration of the source video as the end time for the sub clip.

source_video = VideoFileClip("sample_video_clip.mp4")

`start_time = float(start_time_entry.get())`
eg: 6 seconds

The user did not specify the end time so the program uses the duration of source clip using the moviepy duration function

`end_time = source_video.duration` eg. 56.11 seconds

I then try to display the frames that relate to the these time locations

```
        end_frame_image_array = source_video.get_frame(end_time) 
        end_frame_image_location = Image.fromarray(end_frame_image_array)
        end_frame_image_resized = end_frame_image_location.resize((150,100))
        end_frame_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(end_frame_image_resized)
        end_frame_label.config(image=end_frame_image)
```

The following error appears.

> OSError: MoviePy error: failed to read the first frame of video file
> C:/Users/.../sample_video_clip.mp4.
> That might mean that the file is corrupted. That may also mean that
> you are using a deprecated version of FFMPEG. On Ubuntu/Debian for
> instance the version in the repos is deprecated. Please update to a
> recent version from the website.

**If the user enters a valid end time not including manually entering 56.11seconds (the duration of the clip) the frame is displayed**.

The start frame is also displayed using similar code and works fine

Edit 1.0: Tried using other .mp4 files and the error continues. I don't think its related to the file being corrupted as I can open the files in the media player and also import them into Adobe premier pro 2015

Edit 2.0: looked at the frame.1 seconds from the end time and the image is displayed (see code change below). Error continues if `-.1` is not included

```
end_frame_image_array = source_video.get_frame((end_time-.1))
```

Edit 3.0: Manually entered time clips until I got to this error
Source Clip duration (length) = 56.11 seconds
entering 56.038 seconds as the end time generates the clip as desired
entering 56.04 and upwards brings up the error stated above

Comment: I don't think it is related to your problem but you have to keep a reference to `end_frame_image` so add `end_frame_label.image = end_frame_image`

Comment: @TheLizzard Thank you, added this. Could you explain why? Relatively new to this (first Q on SO etc.)

Did not fix the issue

Comment: It wasn't supposed to fix the issue. It was supposed to avoid [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29401903/11106801) issue

Comment: Have you tried to print `repr(end_time)` to see if  there might be a type difference compared to when the user specifies the end time?

Comment: @j_4321 After further testing, manually entering 56.11 does not work. I have edited the original post. Earlier I was entering 56s without the .11

Comment: @j_4321 Printing these I get the same 56.11 if it is performed by the user  end_time = float(end_time_entry.get() or generated by the end_time = source_video.duration

Comment: Given the edit, the issue seems to be that`.get_frame()` considers times >= 56.04 as beyond the end time and fails to return the corresponding frame. This is inconsistent with the end time provided by `source_video.duration` so you should report it if it has not been done yet: https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues

Comment: @j_4321 Thank you! Will do this. No sign of this issue there so have logged it now.